# Calling StoredProcedure with SimpleJdbcCall Thrwoing class cast exception if parameter is of type LocalDateTime

Tags: mysql, java-8, spring-jdbc

I am calling stored procedure. Here is the my Spring setup and class

Spring setup

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:database/jdbc.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
     public DataSource mySqlDataSource() {
         BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.mysql.driverClassName"));
         ...
         return dataSource;
     }

     @Bean
     public JdbcTemplate mySqlJdbcTemplate() {
         JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(mySqlDataSource());
         return jdbcTemplate;
     }
}
```

Dao class

```
@Repository
public class MySQLCourseRenewalDaoImpl implements MySQLCourseRenewalDao {

    @Inject
    private JdbcTemplate mySqlJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public void callStoredProcedure(String storedProcedureName, Map<String, Object> inParamMap) throws Exception {

        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(mySqlJdbcTemplate).withProcedureName(storedProcedureName);
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParamMap);
        Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
    }
}
```

In `inParamMap` I am putting a parameter like

```
LocalDateTime iUserCourseCourseCompletionDate = userCourse.getCourseCompletionDate();
inParamMap.put("iUserCourseCourseCompletionDate", Timestamp.valueOf(iUserCourseCourseCompletionDate));
```

If I remove `Timestamp.valueOf` and just use `inParamMap.put("iUserCourseCourseCompletionDate",iUserCourseCourseCompletionDate);`. Then when stored procedure runs then I get the following exception

```
CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call usp_processCourseRenewal(?, ?, ?, )}]; Cannot convert class java.time.LocalDateTime to SQL type requested due to java.lang.ClassCastException - java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.util.Date; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert class java.time.LocalDateTime to SQL type requested due to java.lang.ClassCastException - java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to java.util.Date
```

With TimeStamp and java.util.Date stored procedure works fine. Is there any way stored procedure call works with Java8 date time APIs too.

I am using spring 4.2.2

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JDBC + Postgres SQL + Java 8 - conversion from/to LocalDate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536969/spring-jdbc-postgres-sql-java-8-conversion-from-to-localdate)