# Save LocalDateTime with namedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a list of 4 million generated entities that I want to move into table. The entity have field with type  `LocalDateTime`:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor

@Entity
@Table(name = "invoices")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "exact_iss_time")
    private LocalDateTime exactIssueTime;

    @Column(name = "final_iss_time")
    private LocalDateTime finalIssueTime;

    @Column(name = "issuer")
    private String issuer;

    @Column(name = "groupid")
    private Integer groupID;

    protected Invoice() {
    }

}
```

As it is a big number of entities I want to do it optimally - which I gues is with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate()` like this:

```
 public int[] bulkSaveInvoices(List<Invoice> invoices){

        String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (:id, :exactIssueTime, :finalIssueTime, :issuer, :groupID)";
        SqlParameterSource[] sqlParams = SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(invoices.toArray());

        int[] insertCounts = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSQL, sqlParams);

        return insertCounts;
    }
```

However I keep getting error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO invoices VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.LocalDateTime. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
```

1. Am I doing this right - if so how to fix this `LocalDateTime` issue in this case?
2. If this is the wrong way than what is the most optimal way to **INSERT** the 4 million generated test entities into the table with Spring-boot?
   database?

Comment: You either have to use JDBC 4.2 (and a compliant driver) or convert the `LocalDateTime` to a `Timestamp` before inserting it into the database. Or assuming yuo are using hibernate use JPA to batch insert and either use `hibernate0-java8` or if you are on Hibernate 5.2 you can just insert it.

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.1 was released before Java 8 and therefore doesn’t support the new Date and Time API.

You can try add convertor, for more check [How to persist LocalDate and LocalDateTime with JPA](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/)

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
        return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
        return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
}
```

Or you can try not jdbc approach, but use [custom JPA batch](https://frightanic.com/software-development/jpa-batch-inserts/)

Comment: check this - [jdbc conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536969/spring-jdbc-postgres-sql-java-8-conversion-from-to-localdate), i use more JPA approach